# Two columns with page span

Tags: margins, two-column, multicol, minipage

this is my first post! I have tried to find a solution before posting.

I have some input put into my `.tex`. The left column is text input by a user. To the right I would like 0..4 pictures, also according to the users wishes.

Minipage would be great. But the text might span over two pages. A `multicol` environment will (AFAIK) allow text in the right column or vice versa. I would like a strict text-left & images-right design for parts of my document

This is my attempt, using `minipages`

[image]

A neat solution might be to increase the right margin and put the images there. But in case the text is just a few lines, the images didnt stick to the right margin.

**Solved** by simply using `\marginpar{\includegraphics{...}}`; see comments by David.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment, but basically it seems that just normal text plus `\marginpar{\includegraphics{...}}` will do what you ask if you set the margin and marginpar widths correctly

Comment: I might have been looking for a more advanced solution than necessary. As long as the graphics is parallel with the normal text. I will try

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: @Ogglord you might need to adjust the default alignment of the graphic in which case `\marginpar{\adjustbox{\includgraphics` adujustbox (from the package of same name) has lots of options for adjusting boxes...

Comment: Take a look at the [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) package.

Comment: @Fran I did actually look at [flowfram](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/flowfram) but since \marginpar solves my problem it seems like overkill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `\marginpar` You might need to adjust the default alignment of the graphic in which case you can use

```
\marginpar{\adjustbox[...]{\includegraphics
```

`\adjustbox` (from the package of same name) has lots of options for adjusting boxes.

the default reference point of a graphic is on its bottom edge which probably is not what you want for this use.